# cURL presents different server response data in output and in trace: why?

Tags: curl

After running the following command:

```
curl --data-binary @request.bin $URL --trace trace.txt > out.txt
```

*out.txt* contains nothing (its size is zero), but in *trace.txt* I can read (among other things) this:

```
<= Recv data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: 30 0d 0a 0d 0a                                  0....
```

I’d expect *out.txt* to contain `30 0d 0a 0d 0a`, or at least to not be empty. Where am I wrong?

---

N.B. The server’s response is “OK”:

```
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0d 0a 0d 0a` means 2 times `CR LF` and it's part of HTTP-dialog exchange between server and client and means "end of http session". I guess zero here `0....` corresponds to `Content-Length: 0` header and it means that server returned empty reply. And you can see it with empty `out.txt`. Are there any reasons for non-empty reply or you want to capture output headers too to `out.txt`?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing. I’m not sure I understand your question, though. I was expecting _output.txt_ not to be empty because I assumed that `30 0d 0a 0d 0a` was the response’s contents.

Answer (score 2):

30 0d 0a 0d 0a it's a terminating zero message from the HTTP server to the client.

This happen in the case where the server uses "chunks of data":

The HTTP specification provides two ways to specify where a request ends. The Content-Length header and the Transfer-Encoding header.

"The Transfer-Encoding header is used to specify that the message body uses chunked encoding. Each chunk consists of the chunk size in bytes (in hexadecimal), followed by a newline, followed by the chunk contents. The message is terminated with a chunk of size zero."

https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling